# HTTPError: Tile URL resulted in a 404 error

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, contextily

I have data on NY State Hospitals with georeferences and want to create a choropleth map with base map. I also tried layering with .plot() with no success.
When I run my code for layered plot no image is shown, and when I run contextily I get this error message:

HTTPError: Tile URL resulted in a 404 error. Double-check your tile url:
https://stamen-tiles-a.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/24/8388574/8388589.png

The conda environement:

```
*conda config --add channels conda-forge*
*conda config --add channels anaconda*
*conda create -n geo python=3.7.0 geopandas=0.4.0 spyder contextily*
*conda activate geo*
```

This is what I am running, beginning to end:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gp
import contextily as ctx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point
%matplotlib inline


usa = gp.read_file("https://alicia.data.socrata.com/resource/cap4-bs3u.geojson")
NY_state = usa.loc[usa['state_abbr'] == 'NY']

ax = NY_state.to_crs(epsg=3857).plot(figsize=(10,10), alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
ctx.add_basemap(ax)
ax
```

The steps above work well and create a nice map. Below is how I manipulated the NY State Hospital data to create make GeoDataFrame and value for choropleth map (Infections Observed/Infections Predicted)

```
polpro_new = pd.read_csv('https://health.data.ny.gov/api/views/utrt-
zdsi/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD&api_foundry=true' )

polpro_new.rename(columns = {'New Georeferenced Column':'Georef'}, inplace = True)

Geo_df = polpro_new.Georef.str.split(expand=True)
Geo_df = Geo_df.dropna()
Geo_df = polpro_new.Georef.str.split(expand=True)

Geo_df.rename(columns = {0:'Latitude', 1:'Longitude'}, inplace = True)
Geo_df['Latitude'] = Geo_df['Latitude'].str.replace(r'(', '')
Geo_df['Latitude'] = Geo_df['Latitude'].str.replace(r',', '')
Geo_df['Longitude'] = Geo_df['Longitude'].str.replace(r')', '')

New_df = pd.concat([polpro_new, Geo_df], axis=1, join='inner', sort=False)

clabsi1 = New_df[(New_df['Indicator Name']==
                         'CLABSI Overall Standardized Infection Ratio')]

clabsi_2008 = clabsi1[(clabsi1['Year']== 2008)]

df08 = pd.DataFrame([Point(xy) for xy in zip(clabsi_2008.loc[:,
'Longitude'].astype(float), clabsi_2008.loc[:,'Latitude'].astype(float))])

df08.rename(columns = {0:'geometry'}, inplace = True)


clabsi_08 = clabsi_2008.reset_index()
df08.reset_index()
New_df_08 = pd.concat([clabsi_08, df08], axis=1, sort=False)


New_df_08['IO_to_IP'] = New_df_08['Infections Observed']/New_df_08
['Infections Predicted']
```

I used the 'coords' DataFrame to create a GeoDataFrame

```
coords = New_df_08[['IO_to_IP', 'geometry']]
geo_df = gp.GeoDataFrame(coords, crs = 3857, geometry = New_df_08['geometry'])
```

Below are the two ways I tried to plot the georefrence data over a base map

```
y_plot = geo_df.plot(column='IO_to_IP', figsize=(10,10), alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
ctx.add_basemap(ny_plot)
ny_plot
```

and

```
geo_df.plot('IO_to_IP', ax=ax)
plt.show()
plt.savefig("my_plot")
```

I am able to create the ny_plot but no base plot, get this error:

*HTTPError: Tile URL resulted in a 404 error. Double-check your tile url:*
*https://stamen-tiles-a.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/24/8388574/8388589.png*

What might be the problem here? How do I go about fixing it?

Again the output I am looking for is a choropleth map of infection ratio (observed/predicted) on a base map of NY State

Comment: Did you go to that url in your browser? It might tell you what is the issue.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559520/change-background-map-for-contextily

Comment: https://github.com/stamen/maps.stamen.com/issues/107

Comment: Clicking on the url tells me that the key does not exist, which makes me think the issue might be in the format of my NY State georeference data.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a bug when the points in your data are too close to each other, see here: https://github.com/geopandas/contextily/issues/199

The fix that is suggested is to add a parameter to the zoom level, e.g.:

```
ctx.add_basemap(ax, zoom=1)
```